# C++ Templates vs. Aggregation

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, templates

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class B {
  private:
    // some data members
  public:
    friend bool operator==(const B&,const B&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const B&);
    // some other methods
};

template <typename T=B>
class A {
  private:
    // some data members
    vector<vector<T> > vvlist;
  public:
    // some other methods
 };
```

My requirement is that the type T that is passed as type parameter must provide definitions for the operator== and the operator<< methods. I do not want to enforce any other restrictions on T.

How can I do this?

One way that I can think of is to Create an Abstract class say "Z" that declares these two methods.

and then write

```
vector<vector<Z> > vvlist;
```

and NOT have class A as a template.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear: if A uses these operators anywhere, your code just won't compile if T doesn't have them. Do you want to do better than that? Besides, T also has to meet the requirements of std::vector - it has to be copy constructible.

Comment: Oh! OK. Then perhaps this example is not a problem. But I just provided them as examples instead of some specific function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens automatically.

If your code calls the operators `==` and `<<`, then the code simply won't compile if the class is passed a type that doesn't define these operators.

It is essentially duck-typing. If it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it is a duck. It doesn't matter whether it implements an IDuck interface, as long as it exposes the functionality you try to use.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are looking for a concept check library. See what Boost has to offer: [Boost Concept Check Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). That link also has a good explanation what concepts are. Quote:

> A concept is a set of requirements
>   (valid expressions, associated types,
>   semantic invariants, complexity
>   guarantees, etc.) that a type must
>   fulfill to be correctly used as
>   arguments in a call to a generic
>   algorithm

In your question, the concept is "type `T` must provide `operator==` and `operator<<`".

Answer (score 0):

You can write a private method in A that would test required stuff on T in compile time.

```
void TestReq(T x, T y)
{
  if (x==y)
    cout << x;
}
```

This way even plain integers would pass and work.

Comment: Not quite. You also have to call this method, otherwise it might just not be compiled. That is, just having this, everything might (would) pass.